# NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined have specified import datetime

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Below is the code and above is the error  have specified import datetime in the begging
Below is the code and above is the error  have specified import datetime in the begging

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [6], line 3
      1 while True:
----> 3     if (datetime.today().weekday() != 6) & (date.today().weekday() != 5):
      5         hours = [9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
      6         minutes = [0,15,30,45]

NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

```
while True:
    
    if (date.today().weekday() != 6) & (date.today().weekday() != 5):

        hours = [9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
        minutes = [0,15,30,45]

        for hour in hours:
            for minute in minutes:
                schedule_time = datetime.time(hour,minute)
                if (schedule_time >= datetime.time(9,15)) & (schedule_time <= datetime.time(15,15)):
                    schedule.every().day.at(str(schedule_time)).do(job)

        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            sleep(300)

    else:

        now_datetime = datetime.now()
        next_datetime = datetime.combine(date(now_datetime.year,now_datetime.month,now_datetime.day + 1), time(9,15))
        sleep((next_datetime - now_datetime).seconds)
```

need solution for the above error

Comment: `datetime` has a weird import structure; you want `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: It seems like you didn't import datetime

Comment: Judging by the error message, this seems to be in a notebook cell. Are you sure you actually *executed* the cell where you think you imported `datetime`?

Comment: import telegram
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import numpy as np
import schedule
import datetime
import os
from time import sleep

Comment: yes  i have imported datetime yet getting the error @user2357112